Decomposition of $A$ torsion $R$-module over a PID $R$, where every element is of the order of some power of a prime $p\in R$
Let $A$ be a module over a PID $R$ such that $p^{n}A  = 0$ and $p^{n-1}A \neq 0$ for some prime $p \in R$ and positive integer $n$. Let $a$ be an element of $A$ of order $p^{n}$. Then need to show there exists a submodule $C$ of A such that $A = Ra \mathop{\bigoplus} C$.$\\$
Claim: $R/(p^n)$ is an injective $R/(p^n)$- module. What I have managed to show is that $Ra$ is isomorphic to $R/(p^{n})$ as R-modules and that the only proper ideals of the ring $R/(p^{n})$ are the ideals generated by $p^{i} + (p^{n})$ for $1 \leq i\leq n-1$. I know to show that $R/(p^{n})$(hence Ra) is an injective $R/(p^{n})$-module I need to show any module homomorphism from $(p^{i} + (p^{n}))$ to $R/(p^{n})$ can be extended to a module homomorphism from $R/(p^{n})$ to $R/(p^{n})$. How do I do that?

I am a bit confused what you are really asking. If you can show $R/(p^n)$ is self-injective (let's assume that) then given any exact sequence $0\to U\xrightarrow{f}V$ and module homomorphism $g\colon U\to R/(p^n)$ then there is a homomorphism $h\colon V\to R/(p^n)$ with $h\circ f=g$. Then
Now by assumption the $R$-module $A$ is actually an $R/(p^n)$-module, so if you take $U=R/(p^n)a$ (the submodule generated by $a$) and $V=A$, in this case $f$ is an isomorphism and a standard argument shows that $A\cong U\oplus\ker h$. So $C=\ker h$.
Hope that helps.
